# NodeJS Pending Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, etcd

I am currently trying to write some NodeJS (v6.11.0) code to talk to etc but when I try to manipulate the data I get back the promise stays stuck in pending. The code is as follows:

```
const { Etcd3 } = require('etcd3');
const client = new Etcd3();

function getMembers() {
  return client.cluster.memberList()
    .then(function(value) {
      value.members.map(function(member) {
        return member.name;
      });
    });
};

console.log(getMembers());
```

And the output when run the CLI is:

```
Promise { <pending> }
```

I'm very new to Javascript so I'm sure I'm missing something but cannot tell what based on my reading thus far.

Comment: yes, getMembers returns a promise by virtue of .then returning a promise

Comment: You want `getMembers().then(console.log)`. You have to wait for the promise to be fulfilled!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The promise is not stuck in pending. JavaScript is an `asynchronous language`, meaning that the `console.log(getMembers());` will be executed before the promise returned by the `getMembers` function is resolved.

If you want to log when the `getMembers` function is resolved, switch your `console.log` to this:

```
getMembers().then(console.log);
```